# Is it possible to put software in a queue to be installed later?

Tags: software-installation

Sometime I find some software that is interesting and want to install it. At office I use pocket WiFi so I do not want to download big files. I want some how to tag these files so I can install them later when I am at home at connected with wifi network (More faster network).

So is there any way that these software installation can be put in a queue, so that when I am at home it can start right away. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are fluent on the commandline it's simple:

```
echo "sudo apt-get install SOMEAPP" >> dopending.sh
```

When at home, run

```
dopending.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

In synaptic manager there is an option in File menu called Save markings and corresponding option to load the saved markings. You can try that.

Answer (score 0):

make a text file containing all the apps `apt-get` like

```
sudo apt-get install VLC
sudo apt-get install python 
...
sudo apt-get install php 
sudo apt-get install MySql
```

save the file with `.sh` extension then run it as:

```
sudo bash AppsDown.sh
```

enter password and take a nap ;-)

Comment: don't forget to mark the file as executable.